# forking a project from GitHub

Tags: github

I want to fork a suggester for elasticsearch from Github.
I'm following the steps on the website, I'm asked to run the following code:

```
git://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin.git
```

Which class shall I run it in ? and shall I create a new project for it or shall I run it in my current project?

I'm working with eclipse and play framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only line where I see "`git://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin.git`" at the [GitHub elasticsearch-suggest-plugin page](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin) is:

> If you want to work on the repository
>
> - Clone this repo with `git clone git://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin.git`
> - Run: `gradle clean assemble zip` – this does not run any unit tests, as they take some time. If you want to run them, better run `gradle clean build zip`
> - Install the plugin: `/path/to/elasticsearch/bin/plugin -install elasticsearch-suggest -url file:///$PWD/build/distributions/elasticsearch-sugges`

So this line is about cloning locally that repo to run the plugin.
It is not about a "class to run". It is an address that the DVCS (Distributed Version Control System) [Git](http://git-scm.com/) must use to clone the repo.

```
git clone git://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin.git
```